# What (minimal) C graphics library provides these functions

Tags: c, linux, graphics, embedded

I have to replace the nano-X stuff in our linux embedded application and need some replacements for the drawing functions `Arc, Rect, FillRect, Ellipse, FillEllipse, Line, Text, DrawImageFromFile`.

Does anyone know of a suitable open source library that I can use to replace these? Ideally it should work with a pixel buffer in 16bit color, so that writing to the linux framebuffer device is possible.

I thought about `libcairo` but that is a rather big package fro just this purpose. The use of Qt 4.7 is planned for the future and I'm sure it contains the necessary drawing functions. Should I go directly with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first library that comes to mind is [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). Also have a look at [GGI](http://www.ggi-project.org/) (It is much simpler than SDL). [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) too have a simple 2D/3D interface but it is C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go directly with Qt (quite a big package too, though) if you're going to use it ; it'll be much easier to handle dependancies, and it'll do everything you want.